# Can't start H2O on Hadoop Cluster - ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, h2o

I'm trying to start H2O on a Hadoop Cluster. Sadly it doesn't work and gives me the error that the class water.hadoop.h2omapper is not found.

The Hadoop environment is HDP in the version 2.6 and includes 5 nodes, where 1 runs the YARN resource manager and 3 nodes are data nodes with the YARN client. The data nodes each have resources of 32GB RAM and 4 CPU cores each. No other applications are running on them. I configured a maximum of 16GB and 3 cores per YARN application on each node in Ambari.

I start the H2O cluster from the terminal (did try on all nodes, same error everywhere) with the following output:

```
[root@host3 h2o-3.14.0.6-hdp2.6]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 3 -mapperXmx 6g -output h2o-test
Determining driver host interface for mapper->driver callback...
[Possible callback IP address: 192.168.20.35]
[Possible callback IP address: 127.0.0.1]
Using mapper->driver callback IP address and port: 192.168.20.35:46619
(You can override these with -driverif and -driverport/-driverportrange.)
Memory Settings:
mapreduce.map.java.opts:     -Xms6g -Xmx6g -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true
Extra memory percent:        10
mapreduce.map.memory.mb:     6758
17/10/13 07:49:14 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at host2/192.168.20.34:8050
17/10/13 07:49:14 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at host2/192.168.20.34:10200
17/10/13 07:49:15 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).

17/10/13 07:49:15 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
17/10/13 07:49:15 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1507793796947_0002
17/10/13 07:49:15 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
17/10/13 07:49:15 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1507793796947_0002
17/10/13 07:49:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://host2:8088/proxy/application_1507793796947_0002/
Job name 'H2O_86929' submitted
JobTracker job ID is 'job_1507793796947_0002'
For YARN users, logs command is 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1507793796947_0002'
Waiting for H2O cluster to come up...
17/10/13 07:49:29 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at host2/192.168.20.34:8050
17/10/13 07:49:29 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at host2/192.168.20.34:10200

----- YARN cluster metrics -----
Number of YARN worker nodes: 3

----- Nodes -----
Node: http://host5:8042 Rack: /default-rack, RUNNING, 1 containers used, 4,0 / 16,0 GB used, 1 / 3 vcores used
Node: http://host4:8042 Rack: /default-rack, RUNNING, 0 containers used, 0,0 / 16,0 GB used, 0 / 3 vcores used
Node: http://host3:8042 Rack: /default-rack, RUNNING, 0 containers used, 0,0 / 16,0 GB used, 0 / 3 vcores used

----- Queues -----
Queue name:            default
Queue state:       RUNNING
Current capacity:  0,11
Capacity:          1,00
Maximum capacity:  1,00
Application count: 1
----- Applications in this queue -----
Application ID:                  application_1507793796947_0002 (H2O_86929)
    Started:                     hdfs (Fri Oct 13 07:49:15 CEST 2017)
    Application state:           FINISHED
    Tracking URL:                http://host2:8088/proxy/application_1507793796947_0002/
    Queue name:                  default
    Used/Reserved containers:    1 / 0
    Needed/Used/Reserved memory: 4,0 GB / 4,0 GB / 0,0 GB
    Needed/Used/Reserved vcores: 1 / 1 / 0

Queue 'default' approximate utilization: 4,0 / 48,0 GB used, 1 / 9 vcores used

----------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Unable to start any H2O nodes; please contact your YARN administrator.

   A common cause for this is the requested container size (6,6 GB)
   exceeds the following YARN settings:

       yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
       yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

---

The corresponding error entry in the system log for the Yarn application:

```
2017-10-13 07:49:24,505 FATAL [IPC Server handler 1 on 40503] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1507793796947_0002_m_000002_0 - exited : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2147)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2239)
... 8 more

2017-10-13 07:49:24,506 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 40503] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1507793796947_0002_m_000002_0: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2147)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2239)
... 8 more

2017-10-13 07:49:24,507 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1507793796947_0002_m_000002_0: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2147)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2239)
... 8 more
```

The full log is available [here](https://pastebin.com/pTz5C7VG).

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,
Markus

Comment: Sorry, there isn't enough information here to say anything meaningful.  Try describing your environment in detail and including all of your command-line commands, the complete output, versions of everything, and any yarn application logs.

Comment: @TomKraljevic I updated my post with additional information. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the partial logs you provided, the following line helps to understand a little:

```
2017-10-12 07:45:02,172 FATAL [IPC Server handler 1 on 39365] 
 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: 
  attempt_1507726330188_0001_m_000002_0 - exited : 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class water.hadoop.h2omapper not found
```

It is clear the task id #2 instance #0 (or first instance) failed due to missing class. So if task #2 shows error, means the other task #1 is already running. Which also means the job has been start or it is in running state. So the problem happened during the job execution stage. It means the DataNode where this particular task was being executed, is not able to find the H2O Driver library. So it is possible the node or the file system on the node is not available due to some reason. If you study your detailed log you will be able to see why this could happen.

[Additional Details]

Either due to permission or file system issue h2odriver.jar is not accessible for any of the mapper and that is the reason your job is not started. You should make sure to fix the Hadoop permissions and accessibility properly so you can launch any "hadoop" command without root and need to super user alias.

Comment: Hey I updated my post with additional information. Looking in the YARN resource manager shows that the job never did run or succeed, so I do think there is another problem. I think maybe the hosts for the data nodes can't read the .jar files, but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run other YARN jobs?  (Like the pi example.)

The application id reveals that your Hadoop cluster that was started on Thu Oct 12 2017 07:36:36 UTC (ie yesterday) and this is the first (and second) job that cluster ever tried to run.

Also, the size of the nodes in the cluster are really really tiny.

All of this looks to me like you are trying to be your own Hadoop administrator and didn't get it to work yet.  :)

Keep trying, and when your cluster is configured properly, H2O will run.